# Scripting Interactive FTP Login

Tags: python, bash, ftp

I'm trying to write a script to log in to 1 of 30+ accounts on a single ftp site which I use for work.

The behavior that I'd like to see:

```
$ ftp ftp.someplace.com
connected blah blah
220 blah blah ready...
Name (something): username
Password: <enter password>
couple lines saying successful login
ftp> <manually enter commands such as ls, cd, get, put, etc>
```

I've tried this in Python with ftplib using FTP.connect()/.login(), but nothing that I found in the ftplib relinquishes control and makes the ftp session interactive.

My next step was to try curl:

```
curl ftp://user:password@ftp.someplace.com
```

This executes and exits with return code 0.

Lastly, I tried ftp from the CLI in a method I would call it from a script:

```
ftp ftp.someplace.com <<END_SCRIPT
> quote USER username
> quote PASS password
> END_SCRIPT
```

This executes and exits with return code 0.

Is there a way to write a script to do this?  I'd prefer this in python, but I'm okay with making a bash subprocess call.  At this point I'm looking at some complex .netrc entry but I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole.
Thanks for your help!

**************EDITED AFTER ANSWERED WITH PYTHON IMPLEMENTATION****************

The following 2 lines in python work:

```
 process = subprocess.Popen("lftp -e ls -u {0},{1} ftp.someplace.com".format(username,password), shell=True)
 output, error = process.communicate()
```

Comment: *"but nothing that I found in the ftplib relinquishes control and makes the ftp session interactive"* - I believe that you do not realize that the *commands* you type in `ftp` *program* are **not** *FTP protocol commands*. Those are commands of that particular FTP client. You do not want to type real low level raw FTP protocol command. It would not work anyway. So if you wanted a Python library to do this, the library would have to implement its own commands (which it would map to local level *FTP protocol commands*) - which may or may not match those of common Linux `ftp` program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would installing [`lftp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp) be feasible? It has a flag, `-e`, that may suit your needs:

```
-e cmd     execute the command just after selecting the server
```

After it executes the command it stays interactive. You could use the following approach where you have one file per account that has the following pattern (name this one, say, `user1.lftp`:

```
open ftp://user1:password@ftp.someplace.com
```

And when you want to connect as user1:

```
lftp -e 'source user1.lftp'
```

This will drop you to a prompt from which you can execute `ftp` commands. You could make it more convenient by defining function like the following in your `.bashrc`:

```
lftp-open() {
    lftp -e "source $1.lftp"
}
```

And then it would be as simple as:

```
$ lftp-open user1
```

Obviously the downside of this, or probably of any approach to automating `ftp` login, is the requirement to store your password in plaintext, so you'd want to ensure that you have the proper read permissions set on the `*.lftp` files.

Comment: Oh yeah, lftp is awesome, thanks!  I like that it also allows tab completion, which is an added bonus.  Thanks!